# Input type=text Formatting Issue Bootstrap React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[Formatting Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psS15.png)

I am using validators for type=text and type=email. I am not sure why the email field is showing the underline for input but the text type is not. Ideas?

```
<form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="input-field col s12">
            <input
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.name}
              error={errors.name}
              id="name"
              type="text"
              className={classnames("", {
                invalid: errors.name
              })}
            />
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <span className="red-text">{errors.name}</span>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field col s12">
            <input
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={this.state.email}
              error={errors.email}
              id="email"
              type="email"
              className={classnames("", {
                invalid: errors.email
              })}
            />
            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <span className="red-text">{errors.email}</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @domenikk added code

Comment: From what you've shown, I see no reason for the different styling. Perhaps you might have some CSS rule somewhere else. If you can setup a codesandbox demo or similar, I could help you more

Comment: @domenikk Thanks for the interaction. Took another look at found this:
`input[type=text]:not(.browser-default){
border-bottom:none;
margin:0;
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@domenikk Thanks for the interaction. Took another look at found this: `input[type=text]:not(.browser-default){ border-bottom:none; margin:0; }`